# why the background image not display completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

Could you please tell me why my background image not display completely .It only display upto the contend why ?I have only header in that so it display only small part of background image

**Here is my code**

```
.button-bar {
    padding:3% 20% 3% 20%;
}    
#wrapper{
    background-image: url(/login);
}
```

Actually I got the answer but 
when I am trying to give margin to my header tag my background image come down .but my header title remain on same position on top .

see this

```
.headerTitle{
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-top:2%;
}
```

Comment: how much of it do you want to show?

Comment: full width and height of image ..full image

Comment: I see two downvotes without any explanation. Please comment with a bit of suggestion if you must downvote a question. We are here to set the tone of this site in a positive way. Please follow what it instructs in the tour pages.

Comment: why developers down voted ? is it a bad Question actually I struck in between .And I new in designing

Comment: The tag on which you are adding background image has no fixed width and height defined. So it will display the background image only to the size of whatever the content inside the `#wrapper` div sets size.

Comment: @SethMcClaine if the given image is 1000X 1000 .it should display 1000X1000 .not 10X10 .I need to display full whole image

Comment: Its too broad and low quality (spelling, code style). Thats why its downvoted. -> no explanation required if its kind of low quality. Welcome to stackoveflow. (I did not vote .. btw)

Comment: @Shruti its a background image not a simple `<img src` image. So it will depend on container size how much image will be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
.button-bar {
    padding:3% 20% 3% 20%;
}    
#wrapper{
      background-image: url("http://s.codeproject.com/App_Themes/CodeProject/Img/logo250x135.gif");
     min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: see this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgawo .it work but if I am trying give some top margin to header my background image change it position

Comment: #wrapper{
      background-image: url("http://s.codeproject.com/App_Themes/CodeProject/Img/logo250x135.gif");
     min-height: 500px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
    }

Comment: please try with that.

Comment: see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgawo ..change .headerTitle{
  margin-left:2%;
    margin-top:2%;

}..change this margin-top:2%; then you will get background image change it position.I need title will come 3% from the top of background image

Comment: how to insert header 3% below the top of background image

Answer (score 2):

Your css is doing exactly what you are telling it to do....

`#wrapper` is just that small slither showing with the background. If you want it to take up the entire page use `.ionic-scroll` in your css instead of `#wrapper`

See image:

http://screencast.com/t/l1ptRRNaDs

Try  replacing `#wrapper` in your css with `.button-bar`, then try `.ionic-scroll` and see the results

```
.ionic-scroll {
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nz1fzunlqzzz7uo/login_bg.png?dl=0);
}
```

If you want the full image to display inside `#wrapper` and you know the image height you can set `#wrapper` height and width like so:

```
#wrapper{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nz1fzunlqzzz7uo/login_bg.png?dl=0);
}
```

If you don't know the height and width of your image I would suggest using an `<img>` tag inside `#wrapper` instead... This will cause `#wrapper` to adjust to the size of the image

Comment: thanks ..for answering ..!! wait I will tell you after a few second

Comment: see this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgawo .it work but if I am trying give some top margin to header my background image change it position

Comment: try using `background-position`

Comment: you should be able to do something along the lines of  `background-position: 30px 0;` (if that pushes to the left flip the `30px` and the `0`)

Answer (score 2):

Because the element with the background is only as high as the elements inside it. So in you wrapper there is only an h4-element with X amount of pixels high, so therefore the wrapper is also X amount of pixels high.

Try adding a min-height to your wrapper and see that the background follows. Like this:

```
#wrapper{
background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nz1fzunlqzzz7uo/login_bg.png?dl=0);
min-height: 250px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0tnjznt5/